# Is it possible to have an Area Under the Curve = 0?

Tags: python, classification, xgboost, roc, auc

I am using `xgboost` for a classification problem.
I have a fundamental question.
Below you can find the AUC for each round for the train and test (unseen) set.
As you can see the AUC for the test set is close to 0. Could you help me in understanding what's going on?

I am using python.

```
[0]     test-auc:0.4375 train-auc:0.881865
[1]     test-auc:0.25   train-auc:0.947957
[2]     test-auc:0.166667       train-auc:0.982759
[3]     test-auc:0.166667       train-auc:0.984674
[4]     test-auc:0      train-auc:0.996169
[5]     test-auc:0      train-auc:0.998723
[6]     test-auc:0      train-auc:0.998723
[7]     test-auc:0      train-auc:0.999361
[8]     test-auc:0.041667       train-auc:1
[9]     test-auc:0.041667       train-auc:1
[10]    test-auc:0.041667       train-auc:1
[11]    test-auc:0.041667       train-auc:1
[12]    test-auc:0      train-auc:1
[13]    test-auc:0      train-auc:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AUC of `0` means the predictor is predicting the wrong class for all samples in the test set.

Looking at the AUC of the training set, it implies that the size of your test set is either too small, or you've selected the wrong (opposite) class for plotting the AUC of your test predictions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The second option (wrong class) is not likely... I double checked. Regarding the first option this is my class distribution...

Train label distribution:
{0: 54, 1: 29}

Test label distribution:
{0: 6, 1: 4}

Comment: I'll say your dataset is altogether small. It is quite easy to wrongly predict 4 out of 4 making the AUC `0`

Comment: OK these results were for 1 of the 10 folds of a cross validation... I will try to set k = 3...